# Form is not returning contents of search, instead it returns "csrfmiddlewaretoken"?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following search bar (which is included in a Bootstrap Navbar):

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-toggler-right" method = "GET" action = "{% url 'search' %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The view that handles the `'search'` url:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        contents_of_search = request.GET
        return HttpResponse(contens_of_search)
```

The problem is is that whenever something is searched in this search bar it returns "csrfmiddlewaretoken" and the contents of the search. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can remove the csrf token from your form, because GET is a safe method. The token is only checked for unsafe methods like POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `name` property in your input text so that you can reference it in request.GET

```
# html template
<input name="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">

# view
query = request.GET.get('query')
```

Comment: It would be great if you'll mark it as an answer :) Thanks!